# restricting input to an integer with max value

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have an input field, that I'd like to restrict the value to an integer only.

I am using the [plug-in TexoTela jQuery numeric](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/) to do this, which works well.

What I'm ideally wanting though, is to restrict this value to lets say `30`, so users cannot enter values above this. (can only enter between 0 and 30)

Could I do this with jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: dude there is something called select box

Comment: made this for ya: http://jsfiddle.net/zV3xD/18/ if you enter more then the 0-30 range the text will become red.

Comment: I'm aware of the select box. I wanted an easier way to simply enter the amount (this is a qty field), so I'd rather people be able to type in a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using HTML5, you could use an `input` element with type `number`:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="30" />​
```

[**-- See Demo --**](http://jsfiddle.net/P9cRZ/)

Alternatively, if you need to support pre-HTML5 browsers, as [one of your comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929863/restricting-input-to-an-integer-with-max-value/10930039#comment14257978_10929863) suggests, you could use a `select` element:

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    .....
    <option>30</option>
</select>​
```

[**-- See Demo --**](http://jsfiddle.net/P9cRZ/1/)

Comment: With html5 you still can have an input higher or lower. So, you can use js/jquery to force the value to be on the range. [--demo--](http://jsfiddle.net/f55eho13/1/)